# Attribute binding in angular

Tags: angular

i am trying to highlighted selected radio button using Attribute Binding but i am not getting result can some one help me please

### css

```
input:default {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px red;
}
```

### html

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" [attr.default]="value=='male'" (click)="value='male'"> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" [attr.default]="value=='female'" (click)="value='female'"> Female<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" [attr.default]="value=='others'" (click)="value='other'"> Other
```

Below my stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-648y1w?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Your selector is wrong

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehh4tr

Comment: `but i am not getting result` - So what is the problem? you do get 3 radio buttons, which is selectable.

Comment: Krish, I think that default it's only for buttons (I'am not 100% sure). In your stackblitz you has input[type=checkbox], must be input[type="radio"] -see that type goes between quotes. You can use simply "checked" in your .css and no code input[type="radio"]:checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css selector is wrong

it should be like this

```
input[type="radio"][default="true"] {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px red;
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnprxh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: demo links to this SO question

Comment: i have small doubt your saying my css is wrong but i followed this official link its working fine https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_default.asp

Comment: can you please explain me ?

Comment: @Krish `The :default selector selects the default form element in a group of related elements.` means when it renders and finds the radio checked on that element css will be applied, your case is of attribute not default selected.